# Como arrastar um elemento livremente na página com javascript puro?

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber como mover um elemento na página livremente com javascript sem frameworks, seria apenas arrastar e largar em qualquer canto da página

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui:http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75422/129

Comment: Queres mesmo fazer isso com JavaScript? o HTML já suporta drag & drop

Comment: Sim amigo, preciso que seja com o javascript puro, sem frameworks

Comment: @TalesBreno olhe todos exemplos, logo o PRIMEIRO é com javascript puro, clique em "Exibir trecho de código" ;)

Comment: Qual é a funcionalidade que pretendes na tua aplicação? Talvez não precises de JavaScript de todo...

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento Obrigado pela tentativa, mas ele não move o elemento livremente na tela, ele só permite soltar um elemento em local premeditado

Comment: @TalesBreno Você poderia [edit] a sua pergunta e adicionar essa informação (arrastar o elemento livremente)? Da forma que a pergunta está, ela é a mesma da que o GuilhermeNascimento postou.

Comment: Eu realmente preciso arrastar o elemento com javascript sem ser o fantasma que o HTML5 proporciona. A pergunta foi editada

Comment: Adicionei um exemplo em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/64342/3635

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para arrastar um elemento eu uso os eventos `onmousedown`, `onmousemove` e `onmouseup` (eu declaro os dois últimos em `window`), se necessário podem ser usados mais eventos.

Para arrastar o elemento de qualquer ponto é necessário subtrair as posições do ponteiro do mouse pelas posições do elemento ao começar à segurá-lo, e assim que o elemento ser arrastado ele obterá a posição do ponteiro do mouse subtraída pelo valor obtido do primeiro cálculo feito quando o elemento foi segurado, por exemplo, no evento `onmousedown`.

**Edit**: mudei a propriedade `"client" + ("X" || "Y")` para `"page" + "("X" || "Y")`, pois ela retorna as coordenadas reais da página e eu não tinha percebido isso.

```js
var dragMe = document.getElementById("drag_me"),
  /* o x inicial do drag*/
  dragOfX = 0,
  /* o y inicial do drag */
  dragOfY = 0;

/* ao segurar o elemento */
function dragStart(e) {
    /* define o x inicial do drag */
    dragOfX = e.pageX - dragMe.offsetLeft;
    /* define o y inicial do drag */
    dragOfY = e.pageY - dragMe.offsetTop;
    
    /* adiciona os eventos */
    addEventListener("mousemove", dragMove);
    addEventListener("mouseup", dragEnd);
}
    
/* ao ser arrastado */
function dragMove(e) {
    /* atualiza a posição do elemento */
    dragMe.style.left = (e.pageX - dragOfX) + 'px';
    dragMe.style.top = (e.pageY - dragOfY) + 'px';
}
    
/* ao terminar o drag */
function dragEnd() {
    /* remove os eventos */
    removeEventListener("mousemove", dragMove);
    removeEventListener("mouseup", dragEnd);
}
    
/* adiciona o evento que começa o drag */
dragMe.addEventListener("mousedown", dragStart);
```

```css
#drag_me {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="drag_me">Drag me</div>
```

Comment: Como concilio as funções ao elemento no HTML, criei a div com o id: drag_me, mas não tive resultado...

Comment: @TalesBreno Você está executando o código quando a página é totalmente carregada ou quando todos os elementos já são declarados? Pois bem, eu fiz um teste e funcionou.

Comment: Sim, verificando no navegador, percebe-se que o código esta alterando via propriedade style o posicionamento do elemento, mas o elemento não esta se movendo como deveria

Comment: me mostre seu código html para ver se me esqueci de fazer alguma marcação

Comment: @TalesBreno Eu adicionei o estilo `position: absolute` ao elemento... Vou transformar isso num fiddle. #Editado

Comment: era o position: absolute mesmo. Obrigado!

Comment: @TalesBreno ^--^ Veja o edit, mudei o `clientX` para `pageX`. Agora funciona com o scroll... eu não tinha percebido isso.

Answer (score 4):

segue uma resposta baseada em uma resposta do Sergio (porém sem o uso de Bibliotecas e Frameworks (a.k.a jQuery).

```js
var Draggable = function (elemento) {
  var that = this;
  this.elemento = elemento;
  this.posX = 0;
  this.posY = 0;
  this.top = 0;
  this.left = 0;
  this.refMouseUp = function (event) {
    that.onMouseUp(event);
  }

  this.refMouseMove = function (event) {
    that.onMouseMove(event);
  }

  this.elemento.addEventListener("mousedown", function (event) {
    that.onMouseDown(event);
  });
}

Draggable.prototype.onMouseDown = function (event) {
  this.posX = event.x;
  this.posY = event.y;

  this.elemento.classList.add("dragging");
  window.addEventListener("mousemove", this.refMouseMove);  
  window.addEventListener("mouseup", this.refMouseUp);  
}

Draggable.prototype.onMouseMove = function (event) {
  var diffX = event.x - this.posX;
  var diffY = event.y - this.posY;
  this.elemento.style.top = (this.top + diffY) + "px";
  this.elemento.style.left = (this.left + diffX) + "px";
}

Draggable.prototype.onMouseUp = function (event) {
  this.top = parseInt(this.elemento.style.top.replace(/\D/g, '')) || 0;
  this.left = parseInt(this.elemento.style.left.replace(/\D/g, '')) || 0;
  this.elemento.classList.remove("dragging");
  window.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.refMouseMove); 
  window.removeEventListener("mouseup", this.refMouseUp);  
}

var draggables = document.querySelectorAll(".draggable");
[].forEach.call(draggables, function (draggable, indice) {
  new Draggable(draggable);
});
```

```css
html, body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.bloco {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  background-image: url('http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/96/96958.svg');
  background-size: calc(100% - 10px);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.draggable {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  transition: transform 0.3s linear z-index 0.3 linear;
  z-index: 0;
}

.dragging {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div class="draggable bloco"></div>
<div class="draggable bloco"></div>
```

Comment: Toby pode colocar um fiddle? Aqui a snipped do SO não está funcionar muito bem, no meu não dá

Comment: Só para constar, jQuery é uma biblioteca, não um _framework_.

Comment: Há uns bugs no drag... ele não quer arrastar às vezes. Isso está acontecendo porque você não declarou os eventos `onmousemove` e `onmouseup` no objeto global `window`.

Comment: @TheProHands apesar do bug citado não está ocorrendo aqui e eu acho que não é necessario adicionar o "mousemove" ao window, acabei por realizar as modificações.